# wpf setting different font for different language in the same sentence

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I am implementing a application that can allow user to change fonts of a sentence in a label. The sentence contains both Chinese and English characters.
What I am done now is user can select one font and that font will apply to both Chinese and English characters.

Now user think that for Chinese characters, another font should be used. Which means that in the same sentence, English characters use font A, and Chinese characters use font B. And font A & B should be let the user choose. This function is just like the font setting in Microsoft word just like the link below. http://blogs.igalia.com/jaragunde/files/2014/04/Word-font-selector.png

Please note that once user choose the font for Chinese, all Chinese characters in the sentence will automatically change to that font. And the Chinese characters in the sentence depends on some input files.

I know there is something in wpf called composite font. But I don't know how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe not a very elegant solution. But you could set a TextBlock as the Labels content and use different Runs for English and Chinese characters.

Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Run" x:Key="EnglishCharacters">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Run" x:Key="ChineseCharacters">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Batang" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Label>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Style="{StaticResource EnglishCharacters}">This is English</Run>
            <Run Style="{StaticResource ChineseCharacters}">你们好</Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label>
```

Comment: what if the Chinese characters in the sentence depends on some input files. Which means the characters are not always the same. I cannot set them in xaml like what you have mentioned: "<Run Style="{StaticResource ChineseCharacters}">你们好</Run>"

Comment: You can of course also bind the text to some property on a view model.

<Run Style="{StaticResource ChineseCharacters}" Text="{Binding Path=ChineseCharacters}" />